# Microsoft Graph present @nextlink even with $top=1?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are querying data using MS Graph OData API, but I found msGraph presents `nextlink` unexpectedly.

For example, even though I intend to query only one record by specifying `$top=1`:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=1
```

in the response there is a `@nextlink`, which leads to another query to this link by our tool.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users",
    "**@odata.nextLink**": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=1&$skiptoken=X%2744537074020001000000223A4164616D73404D333635783231343335352E6F6E6D6963726F736F66742E636F6D29557365725F36653762373638652D303765322D343831302D383435392D343835663834663866323034B900000000000000000000%27",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "6e7b768e-07e2-4810-8459-485f84f8f204",
            "businessPhones": [],
            "displayName": "Conf Room Adams",
            "givenName": null,
            "jobTitle": null,
            "mail": "Adams@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
            "mobilePhone": null,
            "officeLocation": null,
            "preferredLanguage": null,
            "surname": null,
            "userPrincipalName": "Adams@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

One can reproduce it in [graph-explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

Is it working as expected? 
I think there should be no nextlink since I only want one record. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$top=x` doesn't actually mean

> I want you to show me only first x record(s) and ignore the rest

Its role (based on the [query parameter docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters)) is:

> Sets the page size of results.

What you saw is the expected outcome, as using `$top` is one of the cases where paging is used:

> Some queries against Microsoft Graph return multiple pages of data either due to server-side paging or **due to the use of the $top query parameter** to specifically limit the page size in a request.

And further:

> When a result set spans multiple pages, Microsoft Graph returns an `@odata.nextLink` property in the response that contains a URL to the next page of results.

Which precisely answers your question. If you want. feel free to read more about paging [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/paging).

---

Also remember that while using `$top` query parameter it's a good practice to remember about sorting (source: [OData official documentation](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/#TopSystemQueryOption)).

Comment: reasonable and helpful! thank you very much for clarification.

Comment: You're welcome, but please remember to mark answer as accepted if it helped you. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info!

Comment: Pinging @binning to see comment above